# How to resolve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:" while running a Jar file built using IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, build, apache-poi, artifacts

I have some code which basically reads and writes data to excel file using Apache POI. I am running the code in my run and debug mode and it runs fine without any issues, but once I create a jar using the following command

Build -> Build Artifacts -> Build 
or
Build -> Build Artifacts -> ReBuild

And then I try to run the jar I get the following error.

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

I tried the following:

1. Rebuild or clean build
2. Went to Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies and selected all Export check boxes

Line where the code errors out:

XSSFWorkbook workBookObj = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue recreate the "Build Artifact" following are the steps:

1. File-> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> select the existing artifact -> - (hit remove)
2. Delete "META-INF" folder and "MANIFEST.MF" file from src
3. File-> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> select the existing artifact -> + (hit remove)
4. Artifacts -> Add -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies as shown below

[image]

5. Select the class which has the main method and hit OK.
6. Go back to Build -> Build Artificats -> Select your new artifact and click on create artifact as shown below

[image]